# HTML5 Canvas not clearing

Tags: html, canvas

I am using every possible method to clear out the canvas but no luck. As soon as I click back on the canvas, all the previous drawings reappear.

Here is the code.

```
function clearCanvas() {

    //clickX = [];
    //clickY = [];
    //clickDrag = [];
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //curColor = colorBlack;
    //redraw();

    //clickX = new Array();
    //clickY = new Array();
    //clickDrag = new Array();

    context.fillStyle = '#faebd7'; 
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    canvas.width = canvas.width; 
    //context.beginPath();

};
```

Comment: Try `context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)`? And how is this being called, exactly?

Comment: I tried that and that is why I included all the possible combinations in my code. Please see the commented out code. The code is called from a button to clear the canvas.

Comment: I don't think it can be just because of the code you've posted. These methods do work http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/tgxLq

Comment: Did u find the solution ?? If you did please share, i am facing the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, you are using Arrays to store drawing information.
I see you've tried clearing them, but, as far as I know, the best way of clearing is by setting length to zero. Try this:

```
function clearCanvas() {
clickX.length = 0;
clickY.length = 0;
clickDrag.length = 0;
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

Comment: It clears the canvas but when I pick a different color to draw, it is not picking the new color until after I draw for a while. Very strange behavior.

Comment: Here is the code for my color selection: function setColorWhite() {
        curColor = colorWhite;
        redraw();
    };

Comment: how do you store the colour information? Or does changing the colour change the colour of all lines on the screen? 'Cause with limited info, all I can imagine is that if you have your colour in an array, and that array is not being cleared in the clearcanvas function, it will draw, lets say, 100 points as previous colour, and when it runs out of points it will switch to your new colour.

Comment: In my Javascript function, I just declare it as  colorBlack = "#000000",clickColor = new Array(),...should I reset clickColor as well?

Comment: Yes, look at your redraw() functions, all the arrays that it uses to draw on your canvas has to be reset, otherwise it will run through all those with old information before adding new information.

Comment: you are correct. I did not reset all the arrays from redraw(). Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome, I ran in to very similar problems when first learning how to use Canvas and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not clearing (and you have no errors) then either

1. Your `clearCanvas()` method is not being entered, or
2. You're redrawing on the canvas AFTER your `clearCanvas()` call.

Sorry, that's the best I got with the available info :P

Answer (score 1):

You say "As soon as I click back on the canvas". Does that mean that initially the canvas is clearing until  you click on it?  Then that says to me that you have an event handler that is redrawing everything onclick.

Also, verify that your context is still pointing at the correct canvas.
Some canvas work arounds require creating a temp canvas. If you've done that then maybe you are clearing the wrong context. Otherwise I can't see why context.clearRect wouldn't work as you have it.